# HashMap.containsKey(Object key) can't find a key

Tags: java, collections

Sure I do something wrong, but can't realize what :)
I populate a key/value pair collection Map keyValuePairs with data, after I try to check collection for specific key existence in a common way keyValuePairs.containsKey("Name") and get back "false". But keyValuePairs.keySet() gives back set of keys where "Name" exists.

```
public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output) {

Class parsingObject = output.getClass();
Field[] fields = parsingObject.getDeclaredFields();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^{=;]*)=([^;}]*);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(/*input*/"anyType{Id=1; Name=Til afskrivning; LocationId=1; Editable=true; Default=true; Transcribed=false; }");
Map<String, String> keyValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    if(!keyValuePairs.containsKey(matcher.group(1))){
    keyValuePairs.put(matcher.group(1).trim(), matcher.group(2).trim());
}
}

for (Field field : fields) {
    if(keyValuePairs.containsKey(field.getName())){
        //TODO: add values to fields    
    }
}
}
```

output result after matching:

```
 Id=1;
 Name=Til afskrivning;
 LocationId=1;
 Editable=true;
 Default=true;
 Transcribed=false;
```

"keyValuePairs"= HashMap  (id=830062742672) 
{ LocationId=1,  Default=true,  Editable=true,  Name=Til afskrivning, Id=1, Transcribed=false}

> "keyValuePairs.keySet()"= HashMap$1  (id=830062763448)
>   [ LocationId,  Default,  Editable,  Name, Id,  Transcribed]
>
> "keyValuePairs.containsKey("Name")"= false

Could anybody please explain me what's wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your key is "Name", and not "Name " or " Name" or even "\tName" ?

Comment: Might want to include the regex you're using and the source data, which would help answer @Riduidel's question

Comment: Can we get a peak at your matcher regex? It could easily be that you're mis-matching something. It's usually a good idea to normalize String keys before doing a .put(...) anyway though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the information you gave in the question:

```
"keyValuePairs.keySet()"= HashMap$1  (id=830062763448)  
[ LocationId,  Default,  Editable,  Name, Id,  Transcribed]
```

The extra spaces in front of some of the key names suggest that the key inserted was `" Name"` (note the preceding space). If you give more information about the regex, we may be able to figure out why this happened.

You can also debug this yourself by logging/printing what `group(1)` and `group(2)` matches; I'm sure you'll find that it matches the extra whitespaces.

A quick fix is to put `group(1).trim()` and `group(2).trim()` into the map instead, but the better option is to fix the regex.

Comment: I'm going to guess the regex is something like `([^=]*)=(...)`. The solution may just be to add `\s*` in front of group 1.

Comment: @Maxim: if you give enough information, I may be able to convince you to use `Scanner` instead. Or perhaps some other specialized libraries to handle key/value pairs, `java.util.Properties` et.al.

Comment: Question is edited, seems added everything, it's quite simple method to parse each property of soap response.

Comment: @Maxim: I have no experience with SOAP, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468428/how-to-extract-data-from-a-soap-response-in-java